# Предотвращение случайного исполнения команд при вводе в PuTTY текста с \r\n?

Tags: windows, putty

Например если по ошибке скопировать обе строки:

```
echo 1
echo 2
```

И вставить в PuTTy, то первая команда сразу же будет исполнена:

```
user@hostname:~$ echo 1
1
user@hostname:~$ echo 2
```

Нужно предотвратить такое исполнение (или вставку), чтобы команда исполнялась только по нажатию Enter.

Comment: И как Вы себе это представляете? Вы копируете в окно 2 строки, отображается первая, и курсор замирает, ожидая Вашего Enter, а вторая строка "зависает" неизвестно где? Выход имхо прост - не делайте ошибок...

Comment: Это же синтаксис терминала. Как вы себе представляете, как терминал узнает когда вы дописали команду до конца и её надо выполнить? С ваших слов, терминал который игнорирует \r\n никогда такого сделать не сможет...

Comment: Видел решение на AutoHotKey: https://serverfault.com/questions/731022/prevent-accidental-execution-of-commands-in-linux-if-pasting-text-containing-one

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно:

после первой строки напишите `\ &&`

```
echo 1 \ &&
echo 2
```

и так далее, сколько нужно строк ...

например:

```
$ pwd \ &&
> pwd \ &&
> echo test \ &&
> echo "Sehr gut"

/usr
/usr
test
Sehr gut
```